# Failed to start Hadoop datanode. Return value: 1

Tags: hadoop

I created 2 VM (master and slave) 
I installed hadoop components (namenode, hdfs..) 
it works fine on the master but on the slave I get this error when starting datanode:

> Failed to start Hadoop datanode. Return value: 1

[image]

Comment: You should share the log

Comment: Please install Java 8 to run Hadoop

Comment: the problem is not with the java version, because I did the same thing on the master VM and everything is okey, 
on the slave VM I can't find the problem. 
my java version is : "1.7.0_67"

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, JAVA_HOME was not set correctlyy in the /etc/profile. 
I changed the line: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera
by: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
now I can start datanode and tasktracker. 
thank you.